# How can I check whether a Python object satisfies a type constraint?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Let's say I have this type constraint on a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#class-variables):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Sequence
from numbers import Integral

@dataclass
class Coefficients:
    coefs: Sequence[Integral]
```

Now I want to know whether the object `[1, 2, 3]` will satisfy this type constraint. I want to know this as I'm coding/designing, not necessarily at runtime, so both a static checker solution or runtime solution would be fine.

I tried `isinstance()` but it doesn't work with parameterised types:

```
$ mypy -c 'from typing import Sequence; from numbers import Integral; isinstance([1, 2, 3], Sequence[Integral])'
<string>:1: error: Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks
```

```
$ python -c 'from typing import Sequence; from numbers import Integral; isinstance([1, 2, 3], Sequence[Integral])'
[...]
TypeError: Subscripted generics cannot be used with class and instance checks
```

In general I'd like to know how to check objects against *arbitrary* type annotations; while I can easily look up whether `List` is a `Sequence` and `int` is an `Integral`, later I may want to check more complex structures. How do I do that?

Comment: As an aside, I looked for tags re. type annotations, but the only one seemed to be Java specific. Are there more appropriate tags?

Comment: `python-typing` or `mypy` tag

Comment: What IDE are you using? PyCharm has these kinds of features.

Comment: @AlexandreS Sublime Text 3 with Anaconda.

Comment: Can a [post like this](https://medium.com/@erika_dike/setting-up-sublime-text-3-for-python-type-checking-85af5ce1a1ee) or [this one](https://blog.vikborges.com/articles/python-static-type-checking-on-sublime-text-3-with-mypy) help you ?

Comment: @AlexandreS thanks! I already had a lot of that set up, but those posts helped fill in some missing pieces.

Comment: @AlexandreS These resources helped me figure out what was going wrong with Anaconda's interaction with Mypy, so now I have linting in ST3, which is *immensely* useful. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Googling things is a skill you should develop, it can spare you a lot of time.

Comment: @AlexandreS Unfortunately if you Google anything related to type checking in Python, you get millions of hits from pre-2010 devs wondering how they can make it more like Java.

Comment: I meant to say that googling the sentence `sublime text 3 addon python type checking` gave me back those two results. I was sincere saying that googling is a skill that is hard to acquire, I personally had a hard time to do it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the required type, and run mypy on it directly. Mypy has an [open issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2636) about support for the `numbers` module's numeric tower.

```
mypy -c 'from typing import Sequence
from numbers import Integral
x: Sequence[Integral]
x = [1, 2, 3]'

<string>:4: error: List item 0 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Integral"
<string>:4: error: List item 1 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Integral"
<string>:4: error: List item 2 has incompatible type "int"; expected "Integral"
```

Comment: I think I muddied the issue by using `Integral`, `int` would be the more correct thing to use here anyway. But good answer, thanks!